# How to get the User ID in a EventGrid trigger Function App event?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-signalr

I have an `EventGrid` Trigger `Azure Function` (using the isolated worker on `.net7`) that is called each time a client connects a SignalR hub. It is setup like this:

```
[Function("v1-on-connectivity-events-changed")]
public async Task OnConnectivityEventsChangedAsync
(
    [EventGridTrigger]
    EventGridConnectivityEvent eventGridConnectivityEvent,
    FunctionContext functionContext
)
{
  _logger.LogWarning("Event grid trigger received. Data='{ConnectionInfo}'", JsonSerializer.Serialize(eventGridConnectivityEvent));
  ...
}
```

On the client side, the application connects the SignalR via the Negotiate API like this:

```
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(hubEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, options =>
                {
                    //  Adds the application token to the options' header.
                    options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(user.IdentityToken.AccessToken)!;
                    options.Headers.Add("userSid", user.IdentityToken.UserSid);   
                })
                .Build();

...

await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
```

Here is what the `Negotiate` function is doing which returns the URL along with an additional :

```
[Function("negotiate")]
public Task<SignalRConnectionInfo> OnNegotiateAsync
(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "POST")]
    HttpRequestData httpRequestData,
    [SignalRConnectionInfoInput
    (
       HubName = Constants.HubName,
       ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString"
    )]
    SignalRConnectionInfo signalRConnectionInfo
)
{
        return ExecuteAsync(httpRequestData, async claimsPrincipal =>
        {
            IUserPrincipal userPrincipal = await RetrieveClaimsAsync(httpRequestData, claimsPrincipal);

            signalRConnectionInfo.Url += $"&userSid={userPrincipal.UserSid}";
            
            return signalRConnectionInfo;
        });
    }
```

The `OnConnectivityEventsChangedAsync` Function is properly called when the client gets connected. However, it does not provide all the information that I need: the `User ID` is missing.

**Question**

In the [SignalR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/event-grid/event-schema-azure-signalr?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#example-event), it is stated that the connected event should provide the `user ID` along with the `connection ID`. Here is what I get:

```
{
    "Id":"56f3ab25-11d7-41d6-acbb-8429a741d746",
"Topic":"/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR/<signalr_instance>",
    "Subject":"hub/updates",
    "EventType":"Microsoft.SignalRService.ClientConnectionConnected",
    "EventTime":"2022-11-27T19:22:19.2349923Z",
    "Data": { 
         "timestamp":"2022-11-27T19:22:19.2349923Z",
         "hubName":"updates",
         "connectionId":"gmJM_GHVkXsQuS5C1LhdXXXXX"
    }
}
```

What should I do to get the `User ID` along with the `Connection ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to set the `UserId` property of the `SignalRConnectionInfoInputAttribute` to indicate how to get the user ID. In my case, since the user ID is in the header of the HTTP request as `userSid`, I must do the following:

```
[Function("negotiate")]
public Task<SignalRConnectionInfo> OnNegotiateAsync
(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "POST")]
    HttpRequestData httpRequestData,
    [SignalRConnectionInfoInput
    (
       HubName = Constants.HubName, 
       ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString",
       UserId = "{headers.userSid}"
    )]
    SignalRConnectionInfo signalRConnectionInfo
)
{
   ...
   
   return signalRConnectionInfo;
}
```